# Graphql relay array field

Tags: graphql, relayjs, mutation

I am starting to develop for relay coming from Apollo.
I have a dumb server running on a SQLITE3 database just for testing while I am refactoring.
Using [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) on the backen.

Currently I have something like this:

```
{
  root: {
    allFoo: [FooType]
  } 
}
```

I was wondering how I would add a new FooType item to the allFoo list.
On the [getConfigs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-mutation.html#getconfigs-abstract-method) the [RANGE_ADD](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#mutator-configuration) only acts upon connections.
So do I need to make my allFoo type a connection instead of a GraphqlList(FooType) ? Or can I use FIELD_CHANGE somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example: 
https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery/blob/master/frontend/src/app/mutation/AddImageMutation.js#L47

The below example is a demo on how to add an image to the image list.

```
getConfigs() {
  return [{
    type: 'RANGE_ADD',
    parentName: 'User',
    parentID: this.props.images.id,
    connectionName: 'images',
    edgeName: 'newImageEdge',
    rangeBehaviors: {
      '': 'prepend',
    },
  }];
}
```

Hope this helps!